Seeking Original Sanskrit Shlokas of brahma sutra chapter 1 from YouTube Video
I recently came across this YouTube video on vedant philosophy and brahma sutras: https://youtu.be/_wPEEXrgd8g. , but the uploader hasn’t provided the original text or the source of the verses
Hint : in vedio it says it is from brahma sutra chapter 1 section 2

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism

You have to mention at least what the uploader is saying- English translation. Otherwise, nobody will be able to find it.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay here is the transcript

one undivided reality self
00:03:05.480 associated with body sense the sense
00:03:08.940 sense organs mind and intellect Etc
00:03:11.459 associated with that
00:03:14.340 looks as if separate from each other

There he actually recited the sloka but I Can't get it from his voice, actually need reference from the original book for citation and further study's

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay sir can you please help me to get it
